# Idiomatic way to store and iterate over a named nested data structure in Go?

Tags: data-structures, go, iterator, idioms

My question is split into two: (1) what's the best way to store the data for taskList below, and (2) what's the best way to iterate over such a structure?

I want the `task1` named because they are unique tasks and there shouldn't be an ID collision. I want individually named `subtask0` because they are unique tasks with different requirements.

Below is a pseudo-Go representation of my intention:

```
package main

import "fmt"

fn main() {
    const taskList := {
        "task1": {
            "subtask0": "api.example.com/stuff/"
            "subtask1": "api.example.com/stuff/"
            "subtask2": "api.example.com/stuff/"
        }
        "task2": { 
            "subtask0": "api.example.com/stuff/"
            "subtask1": "api.example.com/stuff/"
            "subtask2": "api.example.com/stuff/"
        }
    }

    for i := range taskList {
        for j := range taskList[i] {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", taskList[i][j])
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried struct, but I had difficulty iterating over the struct. I wanted to avoid `map` because Go wouldn't let me store it in a `const`.

Comment: How many subtasks do you have? Are your subtasks' names needed?

Comment: Let's say a fixed but arbitrary amount, meaning the problem might later have 10 subtasks, but once I define it I don't expect the data structure to grow or shrink. The reason why I wanted my nested structures to be named is because I don't want collision among unique ID's.

Comment: But do you need the names? Like `task2` or `subtask1`? Will they be used anywhere?

Comment: The only reason I wanted `task1` is because they are unique tasks and there shouldn't be collision. The reason I want `subtask1` is because I will be treating them differently (some API's want different headers), otherwise I would put them into an array.

Comment: How about adding this in the question? Because from your current 'code', no one can guess that you want to treat them differently

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I saw in your pseudocode and based on what I heard from the comments, I would go with slice of slices of struct:

So I would define a struct:

```
type subtask struct {
    name string
    kind int
}
```

where `name` would be your `api.example.com/stuff/` and `kind` would be a type of your subtask:

> I will be treating them differently (some API's want different
>   headers)

Then your list would look like this:

```
list := [][]subtask{
    []subtask{subtask{"example1", 1}, subtask{"example2", 1}},
    []subtask{subtask{"example3", 1}, subtask{"example4", 2}},
}
```

And fully working example is here <kbd>[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zJCTXjHUlM)</kbd>